# What open source C# library can read/write micro QR codes?

Tags: c#, .net, libraries, qr-code

I am looking for a C# library to generate and read micro QR codes (example below). It would be great if the llibrary could recognise a micro QR code in an image with other things in it (i.e. isolate and read the QR code.)

[image: Micro QR code example]

Answer (score 3):

There is an open source project called [QRCode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20574/Open-Source-QRCode-Library).

> QRCode library is a .NET component that can be used to encode and
>   decode QRCode.

[image]

Comment: I've been working with it, it's great however doesn't support Micro QR codes as far as I can see - it is the best QR code library I've seen though.

Answer (score 0):

Did not work very well for me. 
Try google codes .net port http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Encoding worked fine, but decoding was very bitchy. zxingnet is much more reliable decoding.